# Generating Octomaps

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I can't find the script "generate_color_octomap_from_estimate.sh" for the evaluation on the Benchmark dataset.
There isn't in the RGBDSLAM package ([http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~endres/rgbdslam/rgbdslam.tgz](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Eendres/rgbdslam/rgbdslam.tgz)).

Where can I find it?

many thanks!
Francesco

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11964/generating-octomaps/) by [Francesco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1396/francesco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, forgot to add it to the archive.
It is contained now, so just redownload it.

Don't forget you need the octomap branch mentioned in [section 2.4 on the wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam/evaluation#Octomapping_Requirements).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1